Set privacy on a child page (groups) when another privacy is set on parent (LOGIN)
I've a restricted (LOGGIN) site, and I'ld like to add more restrictions child pages under this restricted site.
So the home page on the site has a privacy set to LOGGIN.
I want that some users, members on the group 'A' see some parts of the site, and members of group 'B' see other parts, and some parts are visible both from 'A' and 'B' (no restrictions in this case).
From the admin, I've tried to set restriction of type 'GROUPS' on sub-pages, but the admin just says the page has already a restriction, given by the home page.
Is is possible to set more restrictions on sub pages ?
I've implemented a simple Privacy field (for editors), with group names choices, and a signal which try to set the restriction 'GROUPS' to the page, with the group set to the View, but I'm not sure it's the way to create such a restriction.
What do you think about this ?

I am afraid the way Wagtail's privacy settings work - settings apply to all pages below that point in the page tree - there isn't a way to apply privacy settings at multiple levels.
Depending on the relationship between the groups and your page tree, you might be able to use the Wagtail privacy settings by leaving the home page public and then applying login-only to some sections and group permissions for A and B to other sections.
If the group permissions need to be more scattered, another option would be to apply per-page permissions in a before_serve_page hook https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#id58 But then that group check would have to be set on each page you want restricted (no cascade as there is with Wagtail's privacy settings)
